# strange behaviour using splice in angularjs orderby

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the demo [Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/vcxlv5GfamX3ugEsiLvP?p=preview)

I has problem since I start to use orderby (line 24). In my app, try to add an item with no priority then add another one with priority, then delete the item, you can see the deleted item went wrong.

I already passed the $index to the function, I have no clue how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know how the `$index` work, but you can just remove the item by item, not the `index`.

HTML:

```
<!-- Now, the deleteTask($index) changed to deleteTask(task) -->
<button  ng-click="deleteTask(task)">
    <span class="deleteTaskBtn">delete</span>
</button>
```

JavaScript :

```
$scope.deleteTask = function(i){
    var index = $scope.tasks.indexOf(i);
    $scope.tasks.splice(index,1);
}
```

Comment: pure js is the way, you saved my days! TQ!

Answer (score 0):

I think orderBy works only on arrays . 
you can check here
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy